# how can useed multi select from statement

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

```
select Pricing 
from Maarj_License_Management_ServerPrice 
where Status=1 
and (IDServer =(select IDServer from Maarj_License_Management_Server 
                 where NumberServer > @NumberServer ))
```

i want to select the Most Pricing  of the direct but not work

Comment: you probably need `and (IDServer IN` instead of `=` -BAH, already been answered, I always end up reanswering review questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select Pricing 
from Maarj_License_Management_ServerPrice 
where Status=1 
and IDServer IN (select IDServer from Maarj_License_Management_Server 
                 where NumberServer > @NumberServer )
ORDER BY NumberServer
```

Comment: but I would like to ask you another question how can order NumberServer  in second select

Comment: like this 
select Pricing 
from Maarj_License_Management_ServerPrice 
where Status=1 
and IDServer IN (select IDServer from Maarj_License_Management_Server 
                 where NumberServer > @NumberServer ORDER BY  NumberServer  )

Comment: No no no have a look at answer I have update my answer and add an ORDER BY clause.

Comment: its not work because the ORDER  i want in second select not for all

Comment: or get the first record in second select how if Smaller the ( NumberServer > @NumberServer)

Comment: why would you use order by in the sub-query ??? the sub-query returns the list of IDServer values and using an Order by clause there wont make any sense and it just getting values to pass to the filter of your outer query which is IN operator.

Comment: It will be much easier if you could show some sample data and the desired result set, an I am not sure if I can understand what exactly you are trying to achieve here